# Serve-static gives 404 when a file starts with dot

Tags: node.js, express

I have an app in production from an year. It has a functionality to import and later provide zipped data files. Today I tested the app with different data where the file name starts with a dot. The app successfully accepted, zipped, and saved the file, however when the front-end requested the same file, the app's back-end gived 404.

I checked that the file actually exists at the requested url. When I replace the leading dot with lower dash, it works.

Here is my app code:

```
const app = require('express')();
const serveStatic = require('serve-static');
const path = require('path');

app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'public/data')));
```

I'm receiving the following error:

[image]

The file is available at the destination:

[image]

All files without the leading dot work. All files with leading dot give 404.

Please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can serve hidden files (those that start with a dot) with `serve-static` with the `dotfiles` option set to `'allow'` (by default it's set to `'ignore'`).

```
app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'public/data'), {
  dotfiles: 'allow'
}));
```

See: https://ewiggin.gitbooks.io/expressjs-middleware/content/serve-static.html

It's the same with `express.static` middleware:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/data'), {
  dotfiles: 'allow'
}));
```

See: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html